# Unable to add view to DrawerLayout

Tags: java, android, mobile

I have a DrawerLayout, but when I add any view to the 
content_View.xml I get this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 
'void android.support.v7.widget.DecorContentParent.
setWindowCallback(android.view.Window$Callback)' on a null object reference
```

Can anyone explain why is this error happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a nullpointerexception and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/62576) Also, asking us to solve a problem with code you've not bothered to include is unreasonable. See [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You need to show us your code, but for now I can tell you that NullPointerExceptions occur when you have an uninstantiated object.

For example, let's say you have the variable `MyClass myVar`, and you want to call the function `doSomething()` on myVar, and it doesn't work. The reason why is that you need to make an instance of MyClass and assign it to myVar like this: `myVar = new MyClass(args...)`.

This is called instantiating. Now, once you've instantiated myVar you can do `myVar.doSomething()`. Look at the following code:

```
MyClass myVar;           // Creates a MyClass object called myVar
myVar = new MyClass;     // Instantiates myVar
myVar.doSomething();     // Executes the function doSomething() on myVar
```